Homeassistant: how to send the result of a Flux script to Grafana?
I am monitoring the solar energy from my solar panels. Every 5 minutes the total generated power [kWh] is saved into InfluxDB. But these are total values, I like to have the energy production per hour [kWh/h]. The following Flux code does that:
from(bucket: "PV/autogen")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "PV-Zeitreihe")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "stromverkauf")
  |> difference(nonNegative: false, columns: ["_value"])
  |> yield(name: "Stromverkauf delta")

but the results do not show up anywhere.
My question is: how do I get this into Grafana? I tried the |> to(bucket: "..") operator, but that is not implemented in HA.
Any hints about how to do this?
Thanks a lot!
Werner

Solved by myself: add data source InfluxDB-flux into Grafana. Then paste the code directly into grafana.

yes, you can do it right within Grafana.
